# How to create a drop down list using tkinter and set it in a specific row/column? (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, dropdown

I'm having some difficulties using tkinter to create a drop down list. 
I'm not looking for creating a menu i want to make a little app to let me add new entries to an excel file. 
Some of the entries are directly typed by the user but others must be selected from a drop down list.

I don't know how to set up this lists so that they appear at the right row/ column.

here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Ajouter une nouvelle entrée")

window.geometry('400x350')

lbl1 = tk.Label(window, text="Numéro OF")
e1=tk.Entry() 
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
e1.grid(column=1,row=0)
lbl2 = tk.Label(window, text="Produit/carte")
e2=tk.Entry()
e2.grid(column=1,row=1) 
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=1)
lbl3 = tk.Label(window, text="Famille")

lbl3.grid(column=0, row=2)

lbl4 = tk.Label(window, text="Test")

lbl4.grid(column=0, row=3)

lbl5 = tk.Label(window, text="Constats technique")
e5= tk.Entry()
e5.grid(column=1,row=4) 
lbl5.grid(column=0, row=4)

lbl6 = tk.Label(window, text="Type de panne")

lbl6.grid(column=0, row=5)

lbl7 = tk.Label(window, text="Solutions")
e7= tk.Entry()
e7.grid(column=1,row=6) 
lbl7.grid(column=0, row=6)

lbl8 = tk.Label(window, text="Composant changé")
e8= tk.Entry()
e8.grid(column=1,row=7)
lbl8.grid(column=0, row=7)

lbl9 = tk.Label(window, text="Qui?")

lbl9.grid(column=0, row=8)

lbl10 = tk.Label(window, text="Quand")
e10= tk.Entry()
e10.grid(column=1,row=9)
lbl10.grid(column=0, row=9)

lbl11 = tk.Label(window, text="Etat")

lbl11.grid(column=0, row=10)

lbl12 = tk.Label(window, text="Commentaires")
e12=tk.Entry()
e12.grid(column=1,row=11) 
lbl12.grid(column=0, row=11)

window.mainloop()
```

you can see that the lables that have an entry to their right side don't need to be modified but for lbl3, lbl4, lbl6,lbl9, and lbl11 i need drop down lists. 
for example for lbl3 i need a list in column 1 row 2 with this 4 entries: 
'XS2444', 'XB3248', 'DEf23', DEf24' and 'DEf2500'.

You will see it more clearly when you open the window.

Moreover for lbl6 i have a list of more than 100 items to put in the drop down list, I don't know how to add them automatically so that i don't have to enter every item.

Thank you very much you will be truly helping!

Comment: For lbl6, do you mean that you have a list of entries, and don't want to put them in one at a time, or that you want to create the entries automagically, and them add them in?

Comment: Have you tried using the ttk combobox?

Comment: Artemis Fowl I want to create the entires automatically.

Comment: Bryan Oakley yes but it showed me so many errors that i gave up on it :s

Comment: @BryanOakley I didn't get pinged for above, so just pinging you on behalf of the OP.